# Building a huge 2D grid of divs in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I want to build a huge divs gird (10000 * 10000) cells for example. I don't need to show the whole gird at once, rather show a small window (10 * 10), and use arrow to lazy load new cells into view as the user navigates through that gird.

Think of it as a game map, once I load a cell I want to keep it, but I only want to lazy-load those cells outside the view port.

I first tried to use floating divs, but soon it proved to be very difficult to maintain order of divs horizontally and vertically as the user randomly navigates in both directions.

I started to think maybe using fixed left, top properties to each cell would be a better choice to keep loaded cells and gaps of unloaded cells in the right place.

I know you would say this is a subjective question and with no code sample, but I believe it's a good question, so here I re-state it:

Is it better to use "float: left" div or "position: absolute" to draw a huge two dimension div grid?

**Edit**

I found it easier to preserve gaps or spaces between previously loaded and nonadjacent cells, for example I might end up with a case like this:

```
...
<div id="cell-9"></div>
<div id="cell-10"></div>
<!-- preserved space or place holder for cells 11-15 -->
<div id="cell-16"></div>
<div id="cell-17"></div>
...
```

So solution should probably take this scenario into consideration.

Comment: Check out. I have updated my answer with code or you can just go at this link https://jsfiddle.net/nindaclaudel/g6jpzhL5/1/#&togetherjs=Kp2JhfnMeG

Answer (score 0):

It depend on what you want to do:

- I will suggest you to use

  `display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; //` 
  on the parent of the divs

  or to use:

  `display: inline-table; //` 
  on your divs
- if you want to progressive load I will suggest also to create you divs and then with javascript, target the last divs on the screen `if(neer to the edges) { load this much divs }`

**Edit**

I made this [link to my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nindaclaudel/g6jpzhL5/1/#&togetherjs=Kp2JhfnMeG) showing how you can use Javascript to add a `flex-box` div and it goes exactily where you place it

Comment: I never worked with flex before. Does it preserve space for unloaded cells? Please check my edit in the question above for more details.

Comment: I checked your example. the preserved space should actually be blank in UI, meaning it should be a gap with width of five cells. In your example there's no space between cell-10 and cell-16.

Comment: You can add a div with the 5 time width of the other (placeholder) and reduce his size progressively with JavaScript. This example I gave, just show you how you can use flex box to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks I get now. But I can't find what advantage does flex have over float in this case.